# CakePHP HABTM Select box in edit mode not populating

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.3

I feel like I'm going insane. Usually I can figure these things out but this one has be truly stuck. I'm using Cake 2.3.7. I noticed there is a bug in earlier versions of CakePHP.

Hope someone can point out where I'm going wrong. On my site I have Articles that have 3 HABTM associations > Flies, Rivers and Lakes. So:

Article - HABTM - Fly
Article - HABTM - River
Article - HABTM - Lake

Controller:

```
...
$flies = $this->Article->Fly->find('list');
$lakes = $this->Article->Lake->find('list');
$rivers = $this->Article->River->find('list');
$this->set(compact('flies', 'lakes', 'rivers'));
```

View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Fly');
echo $this->Form->input('Lake');
echo $this->Form->input('River');
```

This syntax seems to be exactly as described in the manuals for CakePHP 2.x, and it works on my local test system, but as soon as I upload it to my server, it fails.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Also it would help what version of cake is on your local test system and server, if they are the same then your problem is pretty odd.

Comment: I have CakePHP on both my test system (MAMP / Mac) and server (Bluehost.com). Could it be the PHP version on the server (5.4)?

Comment: I don't think you have the version of cake right... I don't think 3.2.7 is out yet... can you clarify?

Comment: Hey Royalty, thanks and great catch. That's a dyslexic typo... ;) So on both my local machine and on the server I'm running CakePHP 2.3.7. I've also updated above.

Comment: Do you get any errors on your server (bluehost)? Did you ever look in the error logs that cake creates?

Comment: I double checked again, all app logs (debug / error) remain clear. I'm still running the app in Dev mode (full logging). On the server I also do not see anything in the log.

Comment: Can you go ahead and retry my answer? Besides this is there anything else misbehaving on server? Are both versions of PHP the same? Is your tmp folder writable?

Comment: I want to kick myself!! I figured the issue had to be environmental given it was working on one system. So I want back and carefully looked at both environments. Though I had CakePHP 2.3.7 installed on the server, I also had an old install of 2.3.0, and somehow my app was pointed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you feed the input options? Like so

```
echo $this->Form->input('Fly',array('options'=>$flies));
echo $this->Form->input('Lake',array('options'=>$lakes));
echo $this->Form->input('River',array('options'=>$rivers));
```

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. Unfortunately that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

For HABTM associations your form fields should be:-

```
echo $this->Form->input('Fly.Fly');
echo $this->Form->input('Lake.Lake');
echo $this->Form->input('River.River');
```

Otherwise what you're doing in the controller looks correct.

Comment: Thank you drmonikeyninja, I tried this and unfortunately it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The server I was uploading to, somehow had a copy of CakePHP 2.3.0 and the app was pointing to it. CakePHP has a known bug that causes this.

Thanks to all who replied.